# Inheriting from a container with non-virtual destructor

Tags: c++, qt, typedef, forward-declaration, qlist

I'm trying to use forward declarations and d-pointers to eliminate some include dependencies. Everything is working well, except that I have used XList typedefs for readability in many places (e.g: `typedef QList<X> XList`).

The workaround for the typedef forward declaration issue is to use inheritance: `class XList : public QList<X>{};`.
QList has a non-virtual destructor. Given the fact that Qt's own QStringList inherits `QList<QString>` and I'm not allocating XLists on the heap, do you see any problems with this workaround? Should I explicitly disallow heap allocations for the XList classes?

Comment: I wonder how important it is removing **all** include dependencies, specially compared to using unsafe, unidiomatic constructs... Sometimes you are better off standing in the middle ground: remove as many dependencies as possible without going into muddy water.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I'm concerned about the unidiomatic-ness of it. As far as I can determine it will be safe, especially if I statically forbid heap allocs, although I wanted to double-check on that too.

Comment: As an alternative, you could create a "FooListDeclare.h" header file, which basically does "#include <QList>\nclass Foo;\ntypedef QList<Foo> FooList;".  I believe this will let you declare the typdef without needing the class definition dependency in any place that you wouldn't already need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what will happen if we define `XList` this way:

```
class XList : public QList<X> {};
```

The following will work as expected:

```
  XList* x = new XList;
  delete x;
```

However the following won't:

```
  QList<X>* q = new XList;
  delete q;
```

`QList<X>`'s destructor will be called but not `XList`'s, if any. That's what a virtual destructor in the base class will do for you.

If you never use heap allocations you should be fine, but you're preparing a trap for the maintainer following you (or even yourself in a few months).

Make sure this assumption is documented and make `XList`'s `new` operator private to prevent heap instantiation as you mentioned.

The safe alternative would be making `QList<X>` a member of your `XList`, that is: prefer encapsulation to inheritance.

Comment: I've discovered that since I am using XLists as QVariant metatypes I can't make `new` private; even though I'm not doing any allocations, QVariant does. The workaround should still work, but it is getting a little too hacky for my tastes.

Answer (score 0):

`QStringList` doesn't define its own destructor.  In this case, even if `QList` was used polymorphically (see blue.tuxedo's example), there isn't a problem since even though the derived class destructor won't get called, there isn't one defined.

In your case, if you require a destructor in your derived class (`XList`), you'll run into problems.  There was a previous discussion about how to get around not being able to forward declare type definitions here:

[Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c)

If you can avoid writing a derived class, you might be better off in the long run.

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster... Just because in the current implementation in your system the undefined behavior does not bite you does not make the code correct.

Comment: Agreed -- developers would have to remember not to write a destructor in the derived class.  Someone will eventually forget, which would just cause hard-to-find problems.  In that sense, you could argue that Qt is taking a risk with QStringList.

Comment: While QStringList doesn't define a destructor, one will be created by the compiler since the base class has a destructor. The typedef trick also won't work because I want the client header to depend neither on X nor QList.