# C++ forward declaration problem

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have a header file that has some forward declarations but when I include the header file in the implementation file it gets included after the includes for the previous forward declarations and this results in an error like this.

```
error: using typedef-name ‘std::ifstream’ after ‘class’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:145: error: ‘std::ifstream’ has a previous declaration.

class ifstream;

class A
{
    ifstream *inStream;
}
// End of A.h

#include <ifstream>
using std::ifstream;

#include "A.h"

// etc
```

Whats the norm for working around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some minimal code?

Comment: You forgot a `;` after `class A` definition, for starters...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't forward declare std:ifstream - just import `<iosfwd>` instead.

ifstream is a typedef.

See here for further details: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/group__s27__2__iosfwd.html

Answer (score 2):

How did you forward declared it? The problem could be in that `std::ifstream` is a [`typedef`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c) and not a class.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have two problems.

The first is that forward declaring a typedef is rather difficult in C++, as Kirill has already pointed out.

Th second is that `ifstream` is a typedef for a specific template instantiation of `basic_ifstream` -- in order for the compiler to be able to expand the template, it must already have the body of the template defined, meaning you can't forward declare an instantiated template.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forward declare some iostreams classes, you can simply include `<iosfwd>`. That header provides forward declarations for these classes.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the semicolon after your class definition of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
namespace std
{
    template<class E, class T> class basic_ifstream;
    template<class E> struct char_traits;
    typedef basic_ifstream<char, char_traits<char> > ifstream;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the following (if you already include std header file before your own, there's no need to forward declare anymore):

In your cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"
```

In your a.h file:

```
using namespace std;
class A {
  ifstream *instream;

};
```