# C++ templates cross definition

Tags: c++, templates

I want to know if is it possible in C++ to do that :

```
 template <typename T> class A { T link;};
 template <typename U> class B { U link;};

 class AA : A<BB> {};
 class BB : B<AA> {};
```

because it generates the error :

```
 error: ‘BB’ was not declared in this scope
 error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

i have tryed to use anticipate declaration :

```
 class AA;
 class BB;

 class AA : A<BB> {};
 class BB : B<AA> {};
```

but it didn't work :

```
 In instantiation of ‘A<AA>’:
 error: ‘A<T>::s’ has incomplete type
 error: forward declaration of ‘struct AA’
```

thank you for your help,

Comment: Can I ask you why do you need that?

Comment: i need to implement association between to object using templates , here objects ares AA and BB

Comment: Such a class design is purposeless. I don't think it is useful in any sense.

Comment: This must be one of the cases where MS Dev Studio is non-compliant, because this works fine for me.

Comment: On the contrary, the code you've shown use [works as is](http://ideone.com/1bsQB). The error you have likely stems from code you *haven't* shown us where the template parameter is used as if it were complete, where it isn't in the case of `A<BB>`. (Although somehow `A<AA>` is mentioned in that error -- more code you haven't shown?)

Comment: code added  [i use g++ Debian 4.6.3-3 compiler]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn’t the templates, it’s the infinite nesting (and yes, technically from using incomplete types to define members). Remove the templates and you’ll get the same issue:

```
struct A;
struct B;

struct A { B x; };

struct B { A y; };
```

Conceptually, this can’t work. Because, really, what you’d get here is an `A` that contains a `B` that contains an `A` that contains a `B` … to infinity. Turtles all the way down.

What *does* work, however, is using *pointer* members instead. Those work with incomplete types, and consequently the code works – and even with templates.

```
template <typename T> class A { T* link;};
template <typename U> class B { U* link;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question I asked some time back. [How to forward declare a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879162/how-to-forward-declare-a-template-class)

Basically, if you are forward declaring a template type, you have to specify all the template parameters.

Comment: this is about template definition here the problem is with template instantiation like doing : A<XX> a;

Comment: I do not see where you instantiate the class. Anyway, you can't resolve the class definition error because template classes are not really classes - they are just templates for creating classes. What you are doing when you code `A<XX>` is making a new class - not an object.

Comment: Yes A<XX> is a class thats why i wrote: [Class AA : A<BB>] !