# declare typedef type

Tags: c++, typedef, declaration

```
struct mystruct
{
    int   i;
    double f;
} ;

typedef mystruct myotherstruct;

//the other .cpp file
struct mystruct;  //OK,this is a correct forward declaration.
struct myotherstruct; // error C2371（in vc2k8）: 'myotherstruct' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Hi all.
Why can't I forward declare myotherstruct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myotherstruct` identifier is not a `struct` tag, it is a *type name* in its own rights. You use it without the `struct` keyword. Once defined, the name cannot be reused for a `struct` tag. In your example, you are not forward-declaring `myotherstruct` type, you are forward-declaring a `struct` with the tag `myotherstruct`, which gives you an error because the name `myotherstruct` has already been taken for the `typedef`.

Comment: Is a struct tag equivalent to a name of type？
mystruct m;

Comment: @LeonhartSquall Curiously, the answer to this question depends on whether this is C++ or C: in C++, structure's tag can be used as a name without `typedef`, while in C you must `typedef` it first.

Comment: Is a struct tag equivalent to a name of type？
when I use mystruct to define a object:
mystruct m;
I always think mystruct is a type name. And I never know it is a struct tag.How can I undersand the struct tag.

Comment: @LeonhartSquall In your example in C++, `mystruct` is both a tag and a type name. You can declare a variable of type `mystruct` either as `mystruct m;` or as `struct mystruct m;`, both declarations are OK. In C only the second one would be OK. You would need to add a `typedef struct mystruct mystruct;` on order to use the first form of declaration (i.e. without the `struct` keyword).

Comment: Can I think like this: forward-declaring only corresponds to a struct tag not to a type name.

Comment: @LeonhartSquall In C++, it would be more precise to say that forward declaring corresponds only to "primary" type names (which include struct tags, because they implicitly define type names in C++) but not to type *aliases*, which are "secondary" type names created from other type names.

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward declare `typedefs` without forward declaration of the `struct` that is typedefed. You should first forward declare the `struct` and then `typedef`

```
struct mystruct;
typedef mystruct myotherstruct;
```