# Forward declaration of typedef struct with object names in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, struct, typedef, forward-declaration

Consider this class from the WinAPI:

```
typedef struct tagRECT
{
    LONG    left;
    LONG    top;
    LONG    right;
    LONG    bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT, NEAR *NPRECT, FAR *LPRECT;
```

I am enhancing it in a class named `Rect` which allows you to multiply/add/subtract/compare two `Rect`s, along with other features. The only real reason I need my `Rect` class to know about `RECT` is because the class features a conversion operator that allows a `Rect` to be passed as a `RECT`, and to be assigned a `RECT`.

But, in the file `Rect.h`, I do not want to include `<Windows.h>`, I only want to include `<Windows.h>` in the source file so that I may keep my inclusion tree small.

I know that structures can be forward declared like so: `struct MyStruct;`
But, the actual name of the structure is `tagRECT` and it has an object list, so I am kind of confused as to how to forward declare it. Here is a portion of my class:

```
// Forward declare RECT here.

class Rect {
    public:
        int X, Y, Width, Height;

        Rect(void);
        Rect(int x, int y, int w, int h);
        Rect(const RECT& rc);

        //! RECT to Rect assignment.
        Rect& operator = (const RECT& other);

        //! Rect to RECT conversion.
        operator RECT() const;

        /* ------------ Comparison Operators ------------ */

        Rect& operator <  (const Rect& other);
        Rect& operator >  (const Rect& other);
        Rect& operator <= (const Rect& other);
        Rect& operator >= (const Rect& other);
        Rect& operator == (const Rect& other);
        Rect& operator != (const Rect& other);
};
```

Would this be valid?

```
// Forward declaration
struct RECT;
```

My thought is no, since `RECT` is just an alias of `tagRECT`. I mean, I know the header file would still be valid if I did this, but when I create the source file `Rect.cpp` and include `<Windows.h>` there, I fear that is where I am going to experience problems.

How could I forward declare `RECT`?

Comment: Just a note. I did the same thing, I also wanted an enhanced Version of the RECT structure. At the end my structures derived from RECT because then no casting is needed when using winapi function expecting RECT as Parameter. I found this as a better solution and something you might take into account

Comment: @user1017443 That's a good idea. I had originally considered it, but I decided against it because I wanted 'Width' and 'Height' instead of 'cx' and 'cy'. Which, that probably isn't a great excuse seeing as how that way requires more writing on the class-users' part.

Comment: But either way that would require including '<Windows.h>' in the file.

Comment: You can still define member functions called Width for example and these just return the member of the RECT structure. And yes deriving is easier from a user perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doesn't need to know the function definition before actually dereferencing the type.

So you can forward declare in your *header* file (because you will not make any dereferencing here) then include `Windows.h` in your *source* file.

**[edit]** Didn't seen that it was a typedef. However, the other answer is wrong : [there is a way to (kind of) forward declare a typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. It's certainly not a good practice, but in this case it's M$'s fault not OP's. It's not really a forward declaration of the typedef, but multiple declarations which have to be compatible.

Comment: Would this be any different if something was declared `extern "C"` or not?  I'm wondering if any of the windows headers are declared that way, and what effect that may have.

Comment: @Kevin Presumably the C interfaces are, but `extern "C"` is a linkage modifier and types and typedefs don't have linkage so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - I was wondering if a struct in C with the same members was a different size than it is in C++ and how that may affect things in other cases, since "struct" and "class" are very very close in C++, but obviously only one of them exists in C.

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply declare a typedef name, and also forward declare the struct name at the same time:

```
typedef struct tagRECT RECT;
```

https://ideone.com/7K7st7

Note that you can't call a function returning incomplete type, so the conversion `operator RECT() const` cannot be called if `tagRECT` is only forward declared.

Comment: You can actually forward declare a typedef (just discovered this, see the link in my answer)

Comment: @MaëlNison: It's not actually a forward declaration of a typedef, it's a full typedef (of an incomplete type).