# Forward-declaring a custom type of another namespace in a header file

Tags: c++

I am using an external library named *custom* (not the actual name) which defines many of its data types in its own namespace. Let's assume that the namespace is named as `custom` as well.

I am trying to make use of a datatype named `DataType`. `DataType` is a custom type defined using a typedef, and let's assume that it can be used in a .cpp file by including `"custom/datatype.h"`

My code has the following setting.

action.h:

```
class Action
{
    Action() {}
    virtual ~Action() {}

    virtual void foo(custom::DataType*) const = 0;
    ...
}
```

some_action.h:

```
#include "action.h"

class SomeAction : public Action
{
    SomeAction() {}

    virtual void foo(custom::DataType*) const override;
    ...
}
```

some_action.cpp:

```
#include "some_action.h"
#include "custom/datatype.h"
...
void SomeAction::foo(custom::DataType*) const
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any proper way to forward-declare `DataType` in `action.h` and `some_action.h` other than including `"custom/datatype.h"` in `action.h`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059665/why-cant-i-forward-declare-a-class-in-a-namespace-like-this

Comment: does your code compile? In action.h you need at least a forward declaration of `DataType`

Comment: @tobi303 My code does not compile, indeed. That's why I was asking how to proceed with this issue. If I compile the code as it currently is, the compiler considers the `custom` and `DataType` in header files to be undefined. If I forward-declare as suggested in the response by Vittorio Romeo, I get another error. (see my comment to his response for the actual error)

Comment: in such a case you should include the error message in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any proper way to define `DataType` in `action.h` and `some_action.h` other than including `"custom/datatype.h"` in `action.h`?

You probably don't want to *"define"* `DataType`, but to [*"forward declare"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) it instead. This allows you to make the compiler aware of a `custom::DataType` which will be defined later.

You can achieve this as follows. In `action.h` and `some_action.h` add the following *forward declaration*:

```
namespace custom { class DataType; }
```

In the `.cpp` files where you're going to need the definition of `DataType`, include `"custom/datatype.h"`.

---

If `custom::DataType` is a *type alias* *(i.e. `typedef`)*, you need to include the header. There isn't a way of forward-declaring type aliases: see [this question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444291/why-cant-i-forward-declare-typedefs) for related information.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it is defined by a **typedef**. Its definition is actually based on some other internal data type used in custom (i.e. library) which is also in the namespace `custum`. So when I forward-declare it in the manner you suggest, I get this error when compiling: **"error C2371: 'custom::DataType': redefinition; different basic types"**

Comment: @ilim: I missed that apologies - edited my answer. You cannot really forward-declare a `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

If `DataType` is a class type or an enum with an underlying integer type, then you can forward declare it in `action.h`:

```
namespace custom {
  class DataType1;

  enum DataType2 : int; 
}
```

The downside is that it may break when you update the library. Well written libraries may have a header full of nothing other than forward declarations, which you may use, so you can look for those (example: `iosfwd`).

Otherwise, there is no recourse from including the header you are given by the library writer.

Comment: I initially thought that, too, but unfortunately, as I noted in the question, it is defined by a **typedef**.  Its definition is based on some other internal data type used in custom (i.e. library) which are also in the namespace `custum`.

Comment: @ilim - Then the last sentence in my answer applies, I'm afraid.