# Forward-declare a typedef

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, c++03

I have got a large header file (~10000 lines) which is auto-generated by a script/program out of my control.

In order to avoid to include this file in the declaration of my class, I forward declare the few types I need:

--myclass.h

```
namespace bl {
   class TypeA;
   class TypeB;
}
// Other stuff and myclass definition...
```

Now it turns out that `TypeA` and `TypeB` are not class-names, but are instead defined inside the auto-generated file as:

```
typedef SomeUnspecifiedClassName TypeA;
typedef AnotherUnspecifiedClassName TypeB;
```

Where by `SomeUnspecifiedClassName` I mean that I can not forward-declare this type-name because it may change under various circumstances.

How can I forward-declare a typedef? (Can't use c++11)

Comment: Can you use the class via references and pointers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration

Comment: The answer to your specific question in your last sentence is already answered in the first related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Depending on where `TypeA` and `TypeB` are being used, you could consider refactoring `myclass` into a template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply - you can't. If you post your specific situations, though, there might be some workarounds to what you want to do.

Comment: I worked around with some macros (a lot of, actually), by typedef-ing directly the "unspecified" types.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a script that extracts the `...UnspecifedClassName` from the `typedef` lines in your auto-generated source file. Then, this script would be the basis of your own auto-generated header file that would forward declare those classes, as well as your `typedef` statements to them. Your `myclass.h` file can then `#include` that header file.

Answer (score 1):

One relatively decent solution that I have found useful on occasion is to create a trivial wrapper class:

Place in a header file:

```
class ClassA;
// now use pointers and references to ClassA at will
```

Place in a source file:

```
#include <NastyThirdPartyHeader>

class ClassA: public TypeA {
public:
  ClassA(TypeA const &x): TypeA(x) {}
  ClassA &operator=(TypeA const &x) {
    TypeA::operator=(x);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Depending on your use case, that may be all you need.