# Why can't you forward-declare a typedef?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Edit: I know that one can't forward declare typedefs, and there are many qs concluding just that (indeed, I *linked* to one). But none of them explain *why* this is disallowed. I'm not looking for a workaround. I want to understand the rationale.

it turns out that you [can't forward-declare a using-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287578/forward-declare-a-typedef) (or typedef). I.e. you can't do this:

**Interface:**

```
class Impl;
using Concrete = shared_ptr<Impl>;
```

**Implementation:**

```
using Impl = std::function<Foo(const Foo&)>; //DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Instead you have to create a one-element class `Impl` that wraps the std::function.

What's the rationale behind forbidding this? AFAICS all one can do with a forward-declared type like `class Impl` is to store pointers or references to `Impl`... and that works even if `Impl` is later defined to be a primitive like `int` or a function pointer or et cetera..

(Note that `typename Impl` doesn't seem to be a valid way of forward declaring a type.)

Comment: Different pointer types don't necessarily have the same size or same internal structure.

Comment: Because a `typedef` isn't real. It is a mirage, a fantasy, a figment of one's imagination. It is merely an alias for something else. If someone ever invents a decompiler for C++-compiled code, the decompiler will not be able to decompile any `typedef`s, because accordingly to the rules of physics of our shared universe `typedef`s do not exist. The compiled C++ code has no trace or evidence of any `typedef`s. And you cannot forward-declare something that does not exist. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik class names "don't exist" by that logic either, but they can be declared

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/Upu7b8baIq0 . Short answer is that it makes correct overload resolution, template specialisation impossible.