# Forward declaring a typedef for a template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, forward-declaration

I know a typedef cannot be forward declared in C++, but I wonder what may be the best solution for the following problem. I have a header file which declares `MyClass` like this:

```
#include <TemplateClassHeaders>

struct MyStruct
{
    // ...
}

typedef Really::Long::TemplateClassName<MyStruct> MyClass;
```

`MyClass` is used in many places, but mostly just as a pointer being passed through Qt signal-slot mechanism. A forward declaration would be all that's needed, but since `MyClass` is a typedef that will not work. Is there a way to avoid adding myclass.h to every header which uses a pointer to `MyClass`?

Comment: `class MyClass;` Google, or even looking at the suggested SO links while you're typing your question, should reveal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @mah Giving it a second thought or at least reading the entire question instead of automatically downvoting it and pointing me to a similar question (with no templates and template arguments) would reveal to you that `class MyClass` will not work (and would not work even if no templates were involved, because of redeclaration).

Comment: @Marian, `class MyClass;` would work if no templates were involved.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, You're right, my bad.

Comment: @Marian @MattMcNabb `class Myclass;` would not work, even if no templates were involved. It would happily compile, but any code using `MyClass` would silently use `class MyClass` instead of the typedef, so for example a function declared as taking a `MyClass *` parameter would be mangled differently depending on whether the typedef is available, leading to link-time errors.

Comment: @hvd Oh yeah.. haven't had enough coffe today. `class Otherclass; typedef Otherclass MyClass;`

Comment: @Marian While I agree that `class MyClass` as I commented on is not correct, the question I linked in fact says the same thing as the answer you accepted here, so it seems that while you accuse me of not reading the entire question, you seem to have not read the answer I directed you towards. Instead you assumed (quite wrongly) that I down voted you; I did not.

Comment: Edited the question title and tags to highlight the difference between this and the other preexisting question.

Comment: I find it **really annoying** that this question was closed as a duplicate of a question, none of whose answers addresses the central issue of this question, namely that the typedef is for a template instance (maybe with argument type another template instance), whose class name may be (virtually) impossible to write down.

Comment: I think the 'marked as duplicate' is incorrect: the link doe snot contain the template case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot forward-declare a typedef. But if you forward-declare the classes it relies on, both `TemplateClassName` and `MyStruct`, you should be able to define `MyClass`.

```
namespace Really {
  namespace Long {
    template <typename>
    class TemplateClassName;
  }
}

class MyStruct;

typedef Really::Long::TemplateClassName<MyStruct> MyClass;

MyClass *p = 0;
```

Comment: This ugly, unnecessary mess needs to be fixed. We have a billion times more advanced features yet something simple as "hey, use this thing **by name**" is basically impossible - one needs internal knowledge of the type _which someone else defined_ to basically **recreate** the typedef!