# How do I forward declare a typedef in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

I have two namespaces (`F` and `M`) where I used typedef to define something. I use the typedef in one namespace to declare a variable in the other namespace.

For example I have these files:

File `M.hpp`

```
#ifndef M_HPP
#define M_HPP

#include "F.hpp"

namespace M{
    typedef std::vector<F::myD> VectorDouble;

class M{
    private:
        VectorDouble Diction;
};
}

#endif  // M_HPP
```

File `F.hpp`

```
#ifndef F_HPP
#define F_HPP

#include "M.hpp"

namespace F{
    typedef double myD;

class MyF{
    private:
        M::VectorDouble myVar;
};
}

#endif  // F_HPP
```

It is immediately clear that these two header files create a circular dependance so forward declaration may be necessary, but how to do that with namespaces and typedefs?

File `namespace.cpp` to drive the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "M.hpp"
#include "F.hpp"

int main(){
    std::cout << "Learning how to access stuff in a namespace." << std::endl;

    F::MyF myFInstance;
    M::M myMInstance;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get an error that my `M` is an undeclared identifier (see exact error message below). I don't understand why `M` isn't seen as a `namespace`.

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ namespace.cpp -o namespace
In file included from namespace.cpp:5:
In file included from ./M.hpp:5:
./F.hpp:12:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'M'
        M::VectorDouble myVar;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

**How can I access a typedef from another namespace?** Is this a forward declaration issue?

Comment: Pull the `typedef` out into it's own header... then `M.hpp` no longer has a dependency on `F.hpp`

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Is it good practice to put typedefs like that in a single header?

Comment: I'd prefer it over the alternative of duplicating the `typedef` between the two existing headers, since you [can't forward declare a typedef, only duplicate the identical definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have created **circular includes**.

By your own coding, your file `F.hpp` can't be compiled without first including `M.hpp`.

And `M.hpp` can't be compiled without first including `F.hpp`.

Therefore, neither header can be compiled.  See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c) for solutions to circular dependencies.

**Edit:**

You can forward declare your typedef like this.

File `F_fwd.hpp`

```
#ifndef F_FWD_HPP
#define F_FWD_HPP

namespace F{
    typedef double myD;
}

#endif // F_FWD_HPP
```

Comment: I recognize that my code has circular dependencies. I know how to forward declare classes, but my problem is not with the classes, but with the namespace and typedefs. How do I forward declare them?

Answer (score 0):

your two headers are included in each other, that would lead to circular reference and with the header gaurds, one file can be completely excluded in one of the other headers.