# How to pre-declare a typedef class in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

For example, class A has a member of class B. In general, for the purpose of minimizing compilation dependency, we often make class A include B's pointer, and pre-declare class B in the class A's declaration. Looks like this:

```
//B.h
class B
{
    ....
};

//A.h
class B;
class A
{
    B*b;
    A();
    ...
};

//A.cpp
#include "B.h"
A::A()
{
    b=new B();
    ...
};
```

But now I have a question: if the class of B is defined using *typedef* like this:

```
typedef class
{
 ....
}B;
```

The previous pre-declared method will not work in this case. How should I pre-declare the class B in A.h?

Comment: `typedef class B foo;` and after just declare your class normally. What is the point to typedef a class like that ? In cpp your class no need typedef. By the way if you don't have circle include just include B header in A header.

Comment: @Stargateur `class B` and `B` are different in this case

Comment: I ask this question because I may use class writed by other people, they declare their class using typedef. I don't want to change their original files. So I want to know whether have method to solve this problem.

Comment: @KevinZhu you can't just include their header in you header ? your A.h can include B.h ?

Comment: A related question [Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

In the code `typedef class { .... } B;` , it is an unnamed class, with `B` being a type alias for the unnamed class.

It is not possible to declare an unnamed class without defining it (i.e. providing the class body); and it is not possible to declare that `B` is a typedef for an unnamed class.

There is no such thing as a forward declaration of a typedef.  In general a typedef can declare an alias for incomplete type that is completed later, but an unnamed class cannot fill either of those roles.

<sub>Removed further advice in response to voter feedback</sub>

Note: the question used the term "pre-declare". The C++ Standard does not use the terms "pre-declare" or the more common jargon "forward-declare". In the standard's terminology, a forward declaration of a class is simply called a class declaration.  This can be clarified by saying "declaration that is not a definition" if it is not clear from context already.

Comment: OP is already doing this, so you may as well just post that last statement as a comment.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. The first sentence answers OP's question , and the rest of the post gives an alternative way to solve the problem OP is having. @barakmanos there's no rule that answers cannot have additional advice . IMO just saying "You can't." is not as useful an answer.

Comment: I did not down-vote your answer (it is correct plain and simple). I only suggested that it might be more appropriate as a comment. My guess is that it was down-voted because the community here consists of a rather large amount of nit-pickers.

Comment: In fact, the first statement is quite useful, since the OP doesn't seem to be aware of the term 'forward-declaration', which you clearly mention. I will up-vote to compensate...

Comment: The answer states that there is no solution to the OP problem and, more importantly, **explains** clearly why that is so. +1 from me.