# Forward declaration of anonymous typedef with bitfields in C++

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration, unnamed-class

I found an answer for a forward declaration of a typedef in C++ (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095798). But my situation looks like this:

```
// a.h
 typedef struct{
    unsigned char bah0 : 1;
    unsigned char bah1 : 1;
    unsigned char bah2 : 1;
    unsigned char bah3 : 1;
    unsigned char bah4 : 1;
    unsigned char bah5 : 1;
    unsigned char bah6 : 1;
    unsigned char bah7 : 1;
 } bah;

// b.h
typedef struct bah;  // Error: using typedef-name 'bah' after struct

 class foo {
   foo(bah b);
   bah mBah;
 };

// b.cpp
 #include "b.h"
 #include "a.h"

 foo::foo(bah b) 
 {
   mBah = b;
 }
```

and I am not allowd to change anything in `a.h` and I want to avoid including `a.h` in `b.h`. How can I avoid this error or what is the right way to forward declarte bah in this situation?

Thany you!
Zlatan

Comment: You need to include the file `a.h` in your `b.h`. If you do this, you don't need to include the file in `b.cpp`.

Comment: Sorry, I want to avoid including a.h in b.h.

Comment: I would expect `typedef struct bah bah;` to work in practice, but I'm not sure whether it's well-defined. The issue is that the class doesn't *have* a name for you to declare...

Comment: Why the typedef at all? There is no need to do such in C++, just write struct bah { ... } and the forward declaration should work fine by writing struct bah;

Comment: just look at the related topics :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c)

Comment: @punkkeks I reckon the double requirement "no changing `a.h`" and "no including `a.h` inside `b.h`" is about hiding a fixed C API in C++ code.

Comment: @punkekes: I know I can only use struct bah {...}, but I am not allowed to change anything in a.h

Comment: @Quentin typedef struct bah bah creates error: using typedef-name 'bah' after struct

Comment: @Zlatan [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab0f4ca7917a1838). Could you show an example?

Comment: You have to include this file. There's no too much choice here.

Comment: @Punkkeks Thank you, in your related topic I found that this is not possible for anonymous typedef like in a.h. No I have to find a nother way. Thany you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to avoid including a.h in b.h

Too bad. b.h depends on the definition of `bah` from a.h. Your wants are at odds with the rules of the language.

> How can I avoid this error

Option 1: Include a.h in b.h. I know you don't want this, but I want to include all options that are available.

Option 2: Don't depend on definitions of a.h in b.h. An example:

```
// b.h
class foo {
    foo();
};
```

A following class could be defined with only a forward declaration of `bah`:

```
class foo {
    foo(bah* b);
    bah* mBah;
};
```

However, even this is not possible unless you can forward declare the structure. So this brings us to...

> what is the right way to forward declarte bah in this situation?

There is no way to forward declare an unnamed struct. Unless you can modify a.h, you cannot give a tag name for the struct. Assuming that you could change a.h, this is how you would do it:

```
typedef struct bah { // struct now has the tag name bah
    // ...
} bah;
```

Since the name of the struct makes the typedef mostly redundant, you could simplify to:

```
 struct bah {
    // ...
 };
```

After this addition, you can forward declare:

```
struct bah;
```

But forward declaration won't allow you to declare variables of type `bah`.

---

PS. Bit fields have no effect on how forward declarations work.

Comment: Okay, now I know this is not possible for anonymous typedefs. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

There are too many dependencies in your solution.
Define blah once in common part of the code. You will avoid redefinitions.

I would recommend define blah in a.h as you did and then:

1) include a.h inside b.h. Include b.h inside b.cpp

2) or include a.h before b.h inside b.cpp

Comment: Okay, now I know this is not possible for anonymous typedefs. Thank you for your effort!