# Forward declaring a hidden typedef in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, forward-declaration

I have a namespace, `N0`, that has sub-namespaces including `N1`. The calling code only knows about the outer namespace. I'd like to write a function in the outer namespace that returns a `std::unique_ptr<N1::T>` where that result is consumed elsewhere in `N0`. However, the caller shouldn't know about `N1`. What I'd like to do is something like:

```cpp
// N0.h
namespace N0 {
    typename T; // This isn't real C++.
    std::unique_ptr<T> foo();
    void bar(std::unique_ptr<T>&&);
}
```

```cpp
// N0.cpp
#include "N1.h" // Get N1::T
namespace N0 {
    typedef N1::T T;
    ...
}
```

That is, I'd like to expose a type that the caller can't see but internally I'd like to actually use a type in a different namespace. This way elsewhere someone could just forward-declare `namespace N0 { class T; }` without having to know that `T` is actually in `N1`.

I could move `T` itself into `N0`, but it really belongs in `N1`.

I could wrap `T` with a dummy class in `N0`, but that's ugly, and the pointer should basically do that.

I could probably make a class `N0::T` that subclasses `N1::T`, but that seems icky too.

Is there no way for `N0` to forward declare that "I have a type and you don't need to know what it is" and have that type actually be in a different namespace? Put another way: Why is `class C; class C{};` legal but `class C; typedef int C;` is illegal? (Likewise `class C; using C = int;` or `typedef C; typedef int C;`.) They seem fundamentally the same to me and I can't think of a clever template trick to get around it. The only difference I can think of is that the typedef version wouldn't be subject to Koenig lookup.

Comment: I don't think so. I just want `N0` to be able to publicly say "I have a type `T`" that you can have pointers to and then privately have `N0` define it as "actually when I say `T` I mean `N1::T`.

Comment: Inheritance might be an option https://stackoverflow.com/a/44136249/597607

Answer (score 0):

I mean you could do this:

```
// N0.h
namespace N0 {
    std::unique_ptr<T> foo();
    void bar(std::unique_ptr<T>&&);
}
```

```cpp
// N0.cpp
namespace N0 {
    typedef N1::T t;
}

#include "N0.h"

namespace N0 {
    // whatever...
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. Where does `T` come from in `N0.h`?

Comment: @Ben From nowhere. Well, the trick here is to include it *after* already defining `N0::T`, so that the code inside the header becomes valid. It's basically something [like this](https://godbolt.org/g/R4wkuo), where the middle namespace is what is in your header.

Comment: But what of the caller of `foo()`? They'll `#include "N0.h"` and get ` undeclared identifier 'T'` right?

Comment: @Ben Jup if you don't specify which `T` you want to use, and you can only use it for a single `T`

Answer (score 0):

In the situation you have described, the foo should be implemented as a template function:

```
namespace N0 {
    template <typename T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> foo(){...};

    template <typename T>
    void bar(std::unique_ptr<T>&&){...};
}
```

And you should using a wrap/overload function to do the final trick:

```
namespace N0 {
std::unique_ptr<N1::T> foo() { return foo<N1::T>(); }
//for bar there is no need to wrap, cause the T could be resolved by parameters.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I've come up with, which seems to work. I still feel like there should be a way to not use "tricks" to make `N1::T` fully hidden from callers:

```cpp
// N0.h
#pragma once
#include <memory>

namespace N0 {
    struct OpaqueObject { virtual ~OpaqueObject() {} };
    std::unique_ptr<OpaqueObject> foo();
    void bar(std::unique_ptr<OpaqueObject>&&);
}
```

```cpp
//N0.cpp
#include "N1.h"

namespace N0 {
   std::unique_ptr<OpaqueObject> foo() { return std::unique_ptr<N1::T>(new N1::T()); }
   void bar(std::unique_ptr<OpaqueObject> &&) {}
}
```

```cpp
// N1.h
#pragma once
#include "N0.h"

namespace N1 {
  class T : public N0::OpaqueObject {};
}
```

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include "N0.h"

int main() {
  auto x = N0::foo();
  N0::bar(std::move(x));
}
```