# how to create a forward declaration of a typedef struct

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have 1 .h file `test.h` containing a class. In this class there's a private method returning a pointer on a type I don't want to make "public", but I want to be able to include this `test.h` file in other source files.

In general, it's easy to use a forward declaration in the .h file:

```
class Foo;
```

But the problem is that this type comes from a C file **that I cannot change** (because it's someone else code that I'm not maintaining) and it's a `typedef`.

So basically my `test.cpp` is:

```
// this type comes from a C file, cannot be changed to struct or class
typedef struct 
{
   int x;
} Foo;

#include "test.h"

static Foo foo;

Foo *Test::private_function()
{
  foo.x = 12;
  return &foo;
}

int Test::compute()
{
   auto *local_foo = private_function();
   return local_foo->x;
}
```

and my `test.h` file is:

```
#pragma once

struct Foo;

class Test
{
public:
  Test() {}
  int compute();
private:
  Foo *private_function();
};
```

trying to compile that fails:

```
>g++ -std=c++11 -c test.cpp
In file included from test.cpp:10:0:
test.h:3:8: error: using typedef-name 'Foo' after 'struct'
test.cpp:7:3: note: 'Foo' has a previous declaration here
```

Currently my workaround is to return `void *` and perform `static_cast` back and forth, but I don't find that optimal. Is there a nicer solution?

(I have checked [Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c) but I tested the solutions and they don't seem to work in my case, maybe what I want to do is simpler/different - I have just a .h and .cpp - or just not possible)

Comment: Unfortunately `typedef`s cannot be forward-declared. A common workaround is to have a C++ class that inherits from the C struct, referenced by its typedef, and you can forward-declare that. This will require some code changes, but they should be minimal.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that looks like a valid answer. I just tried that on my example (`class FooC : public Foo {};`) and it worked. Tme to test that on my real case. So already big thank you :) post your answer and collect 25+

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but note that the `extern "C"` around that `stuct` definition doesn't do anything. There is nothing there that has external linkage. `extern "C"` does not mean "compile this as C code"; it means "generate object code that can be linked with code generated by my local C compiler".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately typedefs cannot be forward-declared.

A common workaround is to have a C++ class that inherits from the C struct, referenced by its typedef, and you can forward-declare that. This will require some code changes, but they should be minimal.

(Posting on behalf of https://stackoverflow.com/users/3943312/sam-varshavchik who commented)

Answer (score 1):

Return this:

```
//#include "SecretFoo.h"
struct SecretFoo {
  uintptr_t handle;
};

//#include "SecretFooImpl.h"
#include "SecretFoo.h"
#include "Foo.h" // definition of typedef struct {int x;} Foo;
Foo* Crack( SecretFoo foo ) {
  return reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(foo.handle);
}
SecretFoo Encase( Foo* foo ) {
  return {reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(foo)};
}
```

now we get:

```
#include "SecretFooImpl.h"
static Foo foo;

SecretFoo Test::private_function()
{
  foo.x = 12;
  return Encase(&foo);
}

int Test::compute()
{
   auto *local_foo = Crack(private_function());
   return local_foo->x;
}
```

and in your header:

```
#pragma once
#include "SecretFoo.h"

class Test
{
public:
  Test() {}
  int compute();
private:
  SecretFoo private_function();
};
```

this boils down to the same binary code, but the `SecretFoo` and paired `Crack`/`Encase` functions provide a safer kind of casting than just a `void*`.

---

This technique is sometimes used in the C world.  `SecretFoo` is a kind of handle; an opaque pointer-like structure.  The data in it (the `uintptr_t handle`) is in this case just a cast pointer; but it could be a pointer into a table of pointers or whatever else.  The `Crack` and `Encase` methods are the only ways permitted to access/create the `SecretFoo`.

Comment: at least it works. But still sounds complicated to me. A static cast to/from `void *` has the same effect and is less complex.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A call to `static_cast<Foo*>(some_void_ptr)` has to know where that `void*` came from.  Which means sufficiently understanding the data flow of `void*`s in your program to understand if that line is correct.  A "strong" `void*` like `SecretFoo` gets produced and consumed in one pair of functions; they need to be mutually validated, and you are done.  Code bases that cast `void*`s are dangerous and fragile as they have no type safety; typed handles like `SecretFoo` are insanely more type safe.  But yes, in a small project with perfect programmers, you'll be ok with `void*`.