# C++ forward-declare a typedef/using statement?

Tags: c++

I know this question was asked in 2009:

[Forward declaration of a typedef in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804894/forward-declaration-of-a-typedef-in-c)

But given that was asked in 2009 is there seriously still no way to forward-declare a typedef/using statement?

Comment: Does the top answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/804956/5754656) not answer your question?

Comment: *But given that was asked in 2009 is there seriously still no way to forward-declare a typedef/using statement?* Yep.

Comment: You cant create an alias of something if that something doesn't exist.

Comment: No. You have to forward-declare the underlying type of the typedef, then you can declare the typedef. There's no demand for doing anything about it, so nothing changed.

Comment: It would be very difficult to add such a feature to the language because, if typedefs could be forward declared, the compiler would not be able to determine identity between the forward-declared typedef and some other type. With forward-declared classes, this is not an issue because identity of classes goes by identity of names.

Comment: The bad thing about is that you cannot pre-declare `typedef struct { /*...*/ } S;` at all – even today...

Comment: In the end it was easier I just move all my typedefs to a single header and include that because that answer in the previous question was effectively redefining the typedef, totally pointless.